# Remove subdirectories with same name from different directories at same level

Tags: command-line, bash, rm

No easy way to explain but this is my question in demonstration.
I have a file server with home directory backups. They read like:

```
/home/ron/Downloads
/home/ron/Documents
/home/rob/Downloads
/home/rob/Documents
/home/tom/Downloads
/home/tom/Documents
/home/don/Downloads
/home/don/Documents
```

How would i delete all the folders called Downloads with one command, not invoking the names of the users, but with a shorthand?

I was thinking:

```
rm -r /home/*/Downloads
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Note: I have a few hundred folders to purge like this on more than one server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `find`:

```
find /home -maxdepth 2 -type d -name Downloads -exec rm -r {} +
```